# What Badges don't you get in Picnic Difficulty?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

I read that i could change the difficulty while in town so when i went to confirm it, on selecting the difficulty option i got a notice. while telling me about the differences between the difficulties the last page talked about how "some" badges can't be obtained in *Picnic*.

Now i've been playing casual and i read that the Badge you get from destroying the Yggdrasil Core post game without the help of the Yggdrasil Virus or Kupala's sacrifice can only be gotten in Expert so i was thinking of switching to Picnic to grind lower level characters on the lower floors to quickly get them up to par with the rest of the party and then switch it to Expert when i'm ready to take on the core.

I am wondering what badges the final page in the notice was talking about that i can't get if i am in Picnic